# how to add IIF in box more than 2 expression builder

Tags: ms-access

I make 3 text box.... inside each one has it's own expression builder, exp:

```
txt_box1=IIf([txtperformance]<20000," 0","") 
txt_box2=IIf([txtperformance] Between 20001 And 27999,"12","")
txt_box3=IIf([txtperformance]>28800," 25","")
```

how can i combine all that 3 in one text box or combine all of them in one expression builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine the `IIF()` in one Textbox:

```
=IIF([txtperformance] < 20000, "0", 
     IIF([txtperformance] Between 20001 And 27999, "12", "25")
     )
```